# PHP add paired values to array, then sort and print

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, directory

Say I have the name of a file and it's full path in two variables, how can I add them to an array, sort the array by the filename (keeping the two values paired, then loop through the array and print it? This is using a directory iterator. I won't list the whole code as it's quite convuluted, so heres a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathToIterate));

foreach($files as $file){

$path=str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"],'',$file->getPathname());
$file_name = basename($path,'.'.$info['extension']);

  // Need code to add $file_name and $path to array //

    };
} 


// Need code to sort array by $file_name //

// Need code to loop through array and print <a href="$path">$file_name</a> //


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = array();

foreach ($files as $file) {
   $path = ... ;
   $file_name = ... ;
   $output[$file_name][] = $path;
}

ksort($output);

foreach ($output as $file_name => $path_names) {
   sort($path_names);  // if necessary
   foreach ($path_names as $path) {
// print stuff
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated thanks to elusive's suggestion

Comment: I think the OP wants it the other way around: Sorting by filenames instead of the full paths.

Comment: Thanks gore, but this seems to still be sorting by path?

Comment: @Tim it sorts by filename (`basename`) first, then by path. Not what you wanted?

Comment: Hmmm yes that's what I wanted, but when I used natsort I'm getting odd results. All the $file_name values start with numbers, so like: 1. File one, 2. File two, 3. File three, but using natsort on this is not working, it seems to be in a completely random order

Comment: @Tim Where's the `natsort` implemented? In sorting the array keys, or when sorting path names? For the former try `uksort($output, 'strnatcmp');`

Comment: uksort($output, 'strnatcmp'); worked a treat, thanks gore! Out of interest, can you explain what was going wrong with natsort? I don't understand why that didn't work?

Comment: @Tim You're welcome. `natsort` sorts an array by values, not by keys.

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain each pair in a simple class.  Then I would use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which allows you to sort an array using a user-defined comparison function.

It's been a while since I've written any PHP, so I might be embarrassing myself with the following (untested) example code, but you should get the idea:

```
class Pair
{
    public $path;
    public $name;
}

function myComparator($p1, $p2)
{
    return strcmp($p1->name, $p2->name);
}

...

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    ...
    $p = new Pair();
    $p->path = $path;
    $p->name = $name;
    $pairs[] = $p;
}


usort($pairs, myComparator);
```

Comment: Thanks Oli, I've never done something like this using classes but I'll give it a bash!